# to select and insert from one table to another

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

In master table I have two field named 'id-->AutpIncrement,Primary key','designation-->varchar'.In registration table 'designation-->INT,Foreign key of Id in designation table'.Now what I have to do is that I have to fire select query i.e. select id from designation where name=;something like this and than have to store it using String.getParameter.After doing all this have to pass result set query
i.e. rs.getInt(1);
and finally int id have to insert.

And one thing more in registration form designation is in drop down menu and done coding as dynamic means designation details appear on the web browser by fetching information from database.
Please help me in code for select and than passing information by insert as I have defined in first paragraph .

Comment: I could not undestand your question, but maybe, what you want is this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: This thing is really bothering me. How can I get my drop-down list from MySQL database and then submit it to another table in Data Base. I only know how to create a static drop-down with html and but how can I make it dynamic.

i have a table STATE in Database and Now i want to populate all the STATE name in the drop down list dynamically then i have to save these STATES ID into another table as its ID's reference I think this will help you to sort out my problem

Comment: You have several distinct issues here, and solving them all are well outside of the scope of StackOverflow. Split your problem: 1. Fetch information from the Database 2. Use this information to build dynamically a list of options 3. Persist into the database. Please make it clear where you are stuck at. Otherwise ask 3 distinct questions. Please note your question is very difficult to read as it stands. You should try to avoid mixing natural language with pseudo-code, or at least use the code formatting like this: `code here` (use backticks: `)

Comment: i have to save these STATES ID into another table as its ID's reference.well I am using select id from state where name=?;

Comment: I am passing sql=select id from state where name=?; and than result set rs=sql.executeQuery();after that I am passing  insert query but showing error. I am explaining table-here stateID is primary key and is master table and in register table there is field state(INT type) which is forign key of stateID .now what I have 2 do is this when person enters detail in register form than his state column should match with stateID in master table than his from there id would pass to register table